# Changing Powershell Script for getting website from IIS to Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I wrote a simple Powershell script that grabs all the websites from IIS, loops over them, discovering all images in the directory tree, then sets the data to an Excel file and saves the file.

Now, I need to change it to connect to all websites in an Azure subscription. How would I do that?

Here is the current script:

```
# Create the Excel doc
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault

# Add the Workbook
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

# Name the Worksheet
$Worksheet= $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$Worksheet.Name = 'Images'

# Set the title row
$TitleRow = 1

# Now, name the columns
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,1) = 'ImageTitle'
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,2) = 'WebSite'
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,3) = 'MetaData'
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,4) = 'URL'

# Make the cells bold
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,2).Font.Bold = $True
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,3).Font.Bold = $True
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($TitleRow,4).Font.Bold = $True


# Get the list of websites
$WebSites = Get-Website | Select Name, PhysicalPath

# Initialize the looping variable
$i = 2

#loop over the sites and write to console
ForEach ($Site in $WebSites)
{
    #get all files that are in the root directory -> children
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $Site.physicalPath -Force -Recurse -Include *.png, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.bmp

    ForEach ($File in $Files)
    {   
        $Excel.Cells.Item($i,1) = $File.Name 
        $Excel.Cells.Item($i,2) = $Site.Name
        $Excel.Cells.Item($i,3) = ''
        $Excel.Cells.Item($i,4) = $File.FullName
        $i++ 
    }   
}

# Now, adjust the columns to fit
$UsedRange = $Worksheet.UsedRange   
$UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\Scripts\Images.xlsx", $xlFixedFormat)
$Excel.Quit()
```

**Edit:**

As requested by [Byron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3919502/byron-tardif), here is the snippet of code for connecting to Azure through Kudu's Rest Api and getting files (I have copy and pasted the functions from the Kudu API module for clarity):

```
function Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName)){
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    else{
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
        return $publishingCredentials
}


function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    $publishingCredentials = Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}

function Fill-MimeTypes(){
    return @("image/gif", "image/x-icon", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/bmp")
}

$MimeTypes = Fill-MimeTypes
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Directories = @()


#Login to Azure Account
Login-AzureRmAccount

#Get the Azure subscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName [Your subscription name]

#Get the resource group name
####$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | where ()
$resourceGroupName = [Your resource group name]

#Get the WebApp name
$Resources = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceGroupNameContains [Your web app name]

ForEach($Resource in $Resources)
{
    #Get the WebAppName
    $WebAppName = $Resource.Name

    #Now, get the publishing creds
    $publishingCredentialsHeader = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $WebAppName $null
    $ApiUrl = "https://$WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/"

    #Now get the list of files in the wwwroot directory
    $InitialList = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=$publishingCredentialsHeader} -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

## After this line, we just have dummy processing code to show a tiny bit of what #the data looks like. Here, we then need to find all directories in wwwroot, hit #the API again, find directories in those directories, hit the API again, etc, #until we're done.

```
    ForEach($Item in $InitialList)
    {
        If($MimeTypes -Contains $Item.mime)       
        {

            Write-Host $Item.name
        }

        If ($Item.mime -eq "inode/directory")
        {
            $Directories.Add($Item.href)
        }
    }
}

ForEach($Directory in $Directories)
{
    Write-Host $Directory
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM API will only let you access the management plane, or the metadata of the resource.

To list the files you will need to use the VFS API's provided by Kudu:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: if you don't mind, could you post the script that you ended up making, I think it would be rather useful.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll post a snippet of it. At this point, the Kudu API doesn't have an idea of recursion, so you need to create a recursive function to be able to query down to the last child directory. But that's just code and has nothing to do with how to connect to your Azure sites.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be broken down into the following steps:

1. Use [Login-AzureRmAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-4.2.0) to log into the destination Azure subscription
2. Use the [Find-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource?view=azurermps-4.2.0) with resource type [Microsoft.Web/sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites) type to find all "sites" in your subscription
3. Iterate over that list with [Get-AzureRmWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/Get-AzureRmWebApp?view=azurermps-4.2.0) to extract the required information.

Comment: "Iterate over that list with Get-AzureRmWebApp to extract the required information." - Any idea how to do that to get the image files from the site?